# Remove Template group from url

Tags: templates, url-title

I've setup a template group called 'landing' and i want to allow users to visit a clean url like the following:

http://domain.com/url_title

At the moment it works if I include the template group (http://domain.com/landing/url_title) so how can I remove the template group from the url?

Through a .htaccess file?

Appreciate any guidance.

N

Answer (score 1):

If you know the specific URLs you want to be redirected, and want to redirect only those, you'd add this (before the standard EE Rewrites):

```
RewriteRule ^url_title$ /index.php/landing/url_title [L]
```

e.g., for multiple:

```
RewriteRule ^url_title1$ /index.php/landing/url_title1 [L]
RewriteRule ^url_title2$ /index.php/landing/url_title2 [L]
```

And, finally, if there's a pattern, you could match on the pattern, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^url_title(.*)$ /index.php/landing/url_title$1 [L]
```

UPDATED: removed a really bad idea I suggested in my first version!

Comment: Hi Jay, that makes sense but it's not the intended result. If i now visit domain.com/url_title I don't reach an entry.

Comment: to test, change this to a 302 redirect (which will change the URL in the browser bar)--e.g.,: RewriteRule ^url_title$ /index.php/landing/url_title [R=320,L]  Does it show you the right page? Does it have the right entry?